# Deleselect uisegmentedcontrol selection after clicking on a save button

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a 3 button UISegmented control for a choice selection. I also have a save button that retrieves the chosen control.

When the save button is clicked I want to have to UISegmentedcontrol cleared (ie the previous selected button unselected). I'm not looking for the setMomentary as I want the selection to stick but also be able to unselect it later.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
[myUISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
```

Comment: This is definitely the better answer

Answer (score 24):

```
myUISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1; //turn off the current selection
```

Answer (score 4):

With Swift 4 and iOS 11, the Apple documentation states for [`selectedSegmentIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618575-selectedsegmentindex):

> The default value is [`UISegmentedControlNoSegment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrolnosegment) (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.

---

Therefore you can use one of the two following implementations in order to remove the selection of your `UISegmentedControl` instance:

```
mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
```

```
mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
```

Comment: In Swift 5 replaced by UISegmentedControl.noSegment